# Assumption Checking for Logistic Regression Issue

Tags: r, regression, logistic-regression, prediction

First Question on here and beginner so go easy on me..

But having an issue with assumption checks for logistic regression when I try to check predicted probabilities, receiving this error

> data$predictedProbabilities <-fitted(final_model)
> Error: Assigned data `fitted(final_model)` must be compatible with existing data.
> x Existing data has 32950 rows.
> x Assigned data has 31396 rows.
> i Only vectors of size 1 are recycled.
> Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

> nrow(data)
> [1] 32950
> nrow(data[complete.cases(data),])
> [1] 27539

Any ideas what the issue is and how I could fix?

Input:

```
#Logistic regression models
model1 <-glm(subscribed ~ nr_employed + cons_conf_idx +euribor3m, 
data=data, family="binomial")
model2 <- glm(subscribed ~ nr_employed + cons_conf_idx + euribor3m + 
emp_var_rate + previous + campaign, data=data, family="binomial")
formula <- subscribed ~ nr_employed + cons_conf_idx + euribor3m + 
emp_var_rate + previous + poutcome + campaign + day_of_week + month + 
housing + contact + education +job
final_model <- glm(formula, data=data, family="binomial")


exp(final_model$coefficients)

#review models
summary(model1)
summary(model2)
summary(final_model)

#check predictive accuracy 
logisticPseudoR2s <- function(LogModel) {                                
    dev <- LogModel$deviance 
    nullDev <- LogModel$null.deviance 
    modelN <- length(LogModel$fitted.values)
    R.l <-  1 -  dev / nullDev
    R.cs <- 1- exp ( -(nullDev - dev) / modelN)
    R.n <- R.cs / ( 1 - ( exp (-(nullDev / modelN))))
   cat("Pseudo R^2 for logistic regression\n")
   cat("Hosmer and Lemeshow R^2  ", round(R.l, 3), "\n")
   cat("Cox and Snell R^2        ", round(R.cs, 3), "\n")
   cat("Nagelkerke R^2           ", round(R.n, 3),    "\n")
}

logisticPseudoR2s(final_model)

data$predictedProbabilities <-fitted(final_model)
```

Comment: Hi Joe! Without actually having a sample of your input data or code, we have to rely on your error messages. From what I can tell here, you have a data.frame called `data` that has 32950 rows. The assigned data, `fitted(final_model)` has 31396 rows. This type of thing commonly occurs after removal of NA cases. Could you perhaps subset your `data` object using `complete.cases()` and see if that fixes your number-of-rows mismatch?

Comment: Hi Andrew, you are correct. I've added my input code to question, with everything running without errors up until this point. But yes I've created a logistic regression model (final_model) from data frame (data). Hopefully this input data helps. I didn't remove any values from the original dataset which is why I'm confused with this error.

Comment: We know you didn't *remove* any data, but if you had `NA` values in any of the predictors they would have been removed automatically.  Please post the results of `nrow(data)` and `nrow(data[complete.cases(data),])` as part of your question ...

Comment: Hi Ben, I have included this output in the question. Thanks

Comment: Joe: the output you added shows there are many missing values in `data`. Only ~27k of your records have a complete set of (potential) observations and predictors. This differs from value of 31396 because `final_model` is not using all variables in `data` (fewer total "variables" ~= more complete cases). You can't get predictions for the NA predictors, without doing some separate e.g. imputation process. If I were you, I would pre-filter `data` such that you had only complete sets of possible predictors and then fit your model(s) using that smaller object.

Comment: Hi Guys, thanks for this, I removed NA cases from data, giving me a complete set and allowing me to fit the final_model. Appreciate the help!